# Find the poles of a function over the rational function field.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V = V(y^{2} - x^2(x+1)) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2$ and $\overline{x}, \overline{y} \in K(V)$. Let  $z = \dfrac{\overline{y}}{\overline{x}} \in K(V)$. Find the poles of $z$ and $z^2$.

I don't know even how to start this question. Can anyone help me?

This exercise is the 2.17 in fulton.

Comment: If nobody else jumps in, I might be able to, but it will help us all if you tell us how much you already know about this situation.

Comment: I have the idea that the poles of z and z² is just the point (0,0).  But I cannot prove it, since in the rational function field one can have the non uniqueness of the expressions, so maybe there is another pole I didn't figure out, but formally I don't know how to prove that the point (0,0) is the only pole (if it is indeed).

Comment: Perhaps you can show that $\bar{x}$ doesn't have any other zeros?

Comment: Have you drawn the picture? Do you see that $z$ is the slope of the line through the origin that passes through $(x,y)$? More than that, since I don’t own Fulton, I’m not sure what your “points” are. Are they primes of the subvariety of affine space, or are they valuation rings contained in $K(V)$? I have this incredibly old-fashioned training in the subject, through which I view any question on curves.

Comment: Thanks for everyone. I figured out.  $z^2$ has no poles since $z^2 = x+1$ which is regular. Now $z$ has just the point $(0,0)$ indeed, since if we define the ideal $J_{z} = \lbrace G \in K[x,y] | \overline{G}z \in K[V] \rbrace$, $V(J_{z})$ is the poles set of $z$. Now since $x \in J_{z}$ (clearly) and $y \in J_{z}$ because in $K[V]$,  $y^2 = x^2(x+1)$, therefore $\dfrac{y}{x} = \dfrac{x}{y}(x+1)$ then the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$ which is the whole $K[x,y]$ is in $J_{z}$, thus $J_{z}$ is the whole ring and by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, $V(J_{f})$ is just the point $(0,0)$

Answer (score 2):

It is essential for you to have the picture of the curve $y=\pm x\sqrt{1+x}\,$ in your mind or physically sitting before you.

Let me answer this in the language and from the viewpoint that I know. There are two points at the origin, $P^+$ and $P^-$, which you can see if you imagine lifting one branch of the curve up above the other. The point $P^+$ has the local uniformizing parameter $z-1$, and $P^-$ has the parameter $z+1$. The zeros of $y$ are the point $(-1,0)$ and the two points at the origin, while the only zeros of $x$ are the origin points. The poles are up at the single point “at infinity”, which has the local uniformizer $y/x=1/z$.

When I was teaching Calculus, I always gave this curve as an example of a parametrization,
\begin{align}
x&=t^2-1\\
y&=t^3-t\,,
\end{align}
and of course the parameter $t$ is your $z$. This parametrization shows that $K(V)$, defined to be the fraction field of $K[X,Y]\big/(Y^2-X^3-X^2)$, is equal to $K(z)$, and you see, looking at what $t=z$ does for you, where the (single) pole of $z$ is.